# Why does this function change list value without pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

If I pass a value to a function doesn't it make a copy of the value so that if I change it within the function it doesn't change the original unless I instead pass its address? This is probably a stupid question, but I can't figure out why this function is changing the value of the list.

```
void array_increment(int list[],int SIZE) 
{
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        list[i] = list[i]+1;
}

int main() 
{
    int c[]={3,1,0,-5,1};
    array_increment(c,5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
        cout << c[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Outputs `4 2 1 -4 2`

Comment: you can't pass an array by value in function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues at play.

1. Plain arrays aren't copyable or assignable.
2. Function parameters such as `int a[]` get *adjusted* to pointer `int* a`.
3. Array names can decay *decay* to a pointer to their first element

That 2nd point means that

```
void array_increment(int list[],int SIZE)
```

is really

```
void array_increment(int* list,int SIZE)
```

and the 3rd point means you can pass array `c` as first argument because it can decay to `int*`.

Answer (score 7):

```
void array_increment(int list[], int SIZE)
```

is equivalent to

```
void array_increment(int* list, int SIZE)
```

so the parameter is a pointer.

For a primitive type like a pointer, it's only a shallow copy. The pointer itself is copied, but what it points to is not. So the `list` variable inside the function still points to the array that lives outside of the function.

Comment: ahh ok, I've so far only passed vectors to functions so I didn't realize it worked that way, thanks.

Comment: @AustinMW, That's part of the reason plain arrays are discouraged. They don't act like most other types.